# Adjust height to floated element

Tags: html, css, css-float

```
<div class="view">
  <img src="http://media-cache-ec2.pinterest.com/550x/cf/4f/36/cf4f36b3f25df6f6af27ca54012dedf1.jpg">
  <div class="details">
    Lorem....</div>
</div>

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.view {
  width: 500px;
}
img, .details {
  width: 50%;
}
img {
  float: left;
}
.details {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;  
  overflow: hidden;
  background: pink;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Is there a way to make `.details` adjust to the height of `img`? Right now `height: 100%` does not seem to do the trick.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GbfJE

Comment: not with CSS. For `%` values to work for `height`, the parent element should have a `height` other than `auto`, auto is the default value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple workaround:

```
.view {
    background:pink;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use javascript (most easily jQuery), which would be quite easy...
Check out this solution:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sKtIb
Notice I have included the jQuery Javascript library